# Composite candidate key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with the fields `First_name`, `Last_name` and `SSNO` as the primary key.  How can I make the full name (first and last) a candidate key?

I think that I can do this using a check constraint, but I am not sure regarding the syntax.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php

Comment: First and last name won't be unique, so you shouldn't use them as a candidate key, I don't think.

Comment: Use unique constraints for candidate keys, not that first and last name is a good choice for a key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a candidate key is a concept in tuple algebra and not Oracle databases. In Oracle you either have primary keys or unique constraints or you don't have them.

For clarification, candidate key is a set of columns which contain unique combination of values, so that this set of columns can be used as the primary key. But as you already have the SSN number as the primary key (which is somewhat acceptable only if your application is running within the US). Hence you don't need to create an explicit candidate key to identify your rows uniquely.

One more thing to note is that combination of first name and last name cannot guarantee you unique values everytime. That is, there could be many people with the same first name and last name. Just to be sure, go to any jail and check for the records of people named Ray Harris and Richard Remirez and you'll get to know. Even in your office you will find two or three people with the same first and last names. Hence it is a bad idea to keep first and last names as primary or unique keys.

Comment: In Oracle or in any other SQL DBMS a candidate key is a *set of columns* which are minimally unique and do not permit nulls. PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE are names of constraints used to define and enforce candidate keys.